# Encoding byte array for performUpkeep() in Chainlink Keepers

Tags: chainlink

We have this code below which will encode a uint256 array into a byte array.

For some reason, `performUpkeep()` will be successful in Remix IDE but not using Hardhat.

```js
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external view override returns (bool, bytes memory) {
    bool flag = false;
    uint256 counter = 0;

    uint256[] memory numbers = new uint256[](10);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i+=2) {
        numbers[counter++] = i;
    }

    bytes memory checkData = abi.encode(numbers);
    return (flag, checkData);
}

function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external override {
    uint256[] memory numbers = abi.decode(performData, (uint256[]));
    console.log("The first number is:", numbers[0]);
}
```

The end goal here is to pass data through to `performUpkeep` succesfully.

Comment: Is this the full code? I don't see any logic that would switch the flag variable to true so that the Keepers know when to run performUpkeep().

Answer (score 1):

The `performUpkeep()` function takes an argument of type bytes. It then decodes that argument into an array of uint256. Before passing data to `performUpkeep()` in Hardhat, you must encode the array of uint256 you wish to pass as an argument according to the [standard EVM encoding format](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/abi-spec.html#abi).

To do so in Hardhat (Javascript) you can use the ethers.js library to access the `defaultAbiCoder` object and encode your arguments using it. An example can be seen below

```
let abiCoder = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder;
let dataEncoded = abiCoder.encode([ "uint[]"], [[ 1, 2, 3]]);
await keeperContract.performUpkeep(dataEncoded)
```